# How can I add multiple values for a particular key in database using the json for a single attribute in spring boot

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot

```
roleId: [3,5,2,1],
userId: 895462
```

Above is my JSON, where I need to map multiple values with same userId for the different roleId attribute to my DB.
where data in DB should enter like
UserID    RoleId
895462    3
895462    5
895462    2
.         .
.         .
etc       etc
Below is the code for my controller setting the values for

```
Bean obj = (Bean) Utils.getObjectFromJson(stringObj, Bean.class);
        obj.setActiveFlag(AppConstants.YES);
        obj.setCreatedBy(AppConstants.DEFAULT_USER);
        obj.setCreatedDate(Utils.getCurrentSqlDate());
        obj.setRecordStatus(AppConstants.REC_STATUS_ADD);
        Bean newObj = Repository.save(obj);
        return newObj;
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm glad that you got a JSON string and a few lines of code, but what's your question? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I need to map the roleId values in multiple columns in my sql

Comment: Than clarify your question with an [edit]

Comment: edited the question...please specify the step you need to be clarified

Comment: Have you read [ask]? If you still don't know how you could possibly write a good question, read [writing the perfect question](https://github.com/shlomif/writing-the-perfect-question/blob/master/README.asciidoc)